# Scroll changes state React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

Added a change in the color of the appbar when scrolling, but the problem is that the useEffect changes the data array. Every time the color of the appbar changes, the array itself changes.

Can it be rewritten in some other way?

```
const colorChange = useCallback(() => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 200) {
        setColor(true)
    } else {
        setColor(false)
    }
}, [])

   useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', colorChange)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', colorChange)
}, [colorChange])
```

The function I use for random arrays

```
import _ from 'lodash'

export const shuffle = (array) => {
    const random = _.shuffle(array)

    return random.slice(0, 2)
}
```

Comment: try to write colorChange without useCallback

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. With ref data no longer changes due to scrolling.

I am attaching the solution:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'
const ref = useRef()
const [color, setColor] = useState(false)
ref.current = color

useEffect(() => {
        const colorChange = () => {
            const show = window.scrollY >= 200

            if (ref.current !== show) {
                setColor(true)
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', colorChange)

        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', colorChange)
    }, [])
```

Comment: I don't think that it is a good practice to put a state inside a ref. Both persist a value when the component is re-rendered, but changing a ref doesn't trigger a re-render of the component. I think you should chose either a ref or a state.

Comment: @Felipe thanks! How then can this be written on the ref?

Comment: Instead of creating the state, you just create the ref to a default color: `ref.current = 'ffffff';` for example. And then instead of using `setColor` to update the state you can just update the ref: `ref.current = `000000`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass colorChange in dependencies of the useEffect. no need for the useCallback. you can define a function inside the useEffect only.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const colorChange = () => setColor(window.scrollY >= 200);
  window.addEventListener("scroll", colorChange);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", colorChange);
}, []);
```

Comment: It did not help. For your understanding, I use 2 random elements from the array

Comment: @TeenDay didn't get you, Can you add same code you are trying.

Comment: @Meesho Added a function. After that I just pass it to the Redux